# Jquery after trigger not working

Tags: jquery

I use the below Jquery to count the table column total after the table changed.
This works properly, even when I apply a searchfilter by hand.

However when I use the below code, the searchfilter gets adjusted and displays according results but the total does not update / counts.

Jquery, table change :

```
 $("table").change(function(){  
    var element = $(this),
    footer = element.find('tfoot tr'),
    dataRows = element.find('tbody tr:visible'),
    initialTotal = function () {
        var column, total;
        //for (column = 1; column < footer.children().size(); column++) {
            for (column = 3; column < 4; column++) {

            total = 0;
            dataRows.each(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                total += parseFloat(row.children().eq(column).text());
            });
            footer.children().eq(column).text(total);
        };
    };
initialTotal();
});
```

Jquery click to change filter :

```
$(".warningdisplay").click(function(){

     var cols=[]
     cols[5] = "3";
    $('table').trigger('search', [cols]);

});
```

I dont understand why the total does not work because when setting the filter by hand it works and also the table is changed so it should exec the function.

What do I get wrong ?

Comment: Did you watch the console? debugging with console can make life easier :)

Comment: Yes, no errors. Somehow when using .trigger the table changes but the function table.change does not work.

Comment: When do you need the change trigger? Whe i want to add listeners while I'm adding something to dom, I use custom events. Or you can simply call the cahnge function when you add a new row

Comment: I need it when the user clicks on a button in my menu, I want it to set specific filter. Still I don't understand it.

Comment: Why don't you call the function on button click?
what does $('table').trigger('search', [cols]); do?

Comment: `<table>` doesn't have a change event. What you are attempting is known as a [mutation event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events). Even when written properly, a mutation event would be pretty sketchy and not a cross-browser solution. Suggest you define a custom event handler, eg 'calculate' and trigger it explicitly immediately after triggering 'search'.

Comment: I guess Roamer-1888 has the answer, but I dont understand that much of it. :(

Comment: Roamer-1888, the  $("table").change(function(){   part works when I select the option manually instead of     $('table').trigger('search', [cols]);

Comment: "option"? Is there some vital piece of information you forgot to include in the question?

Comment: You might have mentioned that you're using tablesorter and tablesorter-widget! I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table's 'change' event is defined by tablesorter-widget. The event is not a generalised DOM mutation event but triggered by other stuff that the widget puts in place, notably by the filter menus.

If you want some external event, such as a click on yout calculator button, to trigger the table's 'change' handler, then I'm guessing that you can trigger the event explicitly.

Something like this should do it :

```
$(".warningdisplay").click(function() {
    var cols = []
    cols[5] = "3";
    $('table')
        .trigger('search', [cols])
        .trigger('change');
});
```